# C#: Date string formatting?

Tags: c#-4.0

I have DateOfBirth in `"11021970"` format but I want this as `"11-02-1970"` format only.

I don't know how to convert datetime to date using c#?

Comment: This is so easy at least you should try

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime.ParseExact("11021970", "ddMMyyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: How can I display this, what variable should I call?

Comment: I assume you gonna get a string, so: `string s = DateTime.ParseExact("11021970", "ddMMyyyy", null).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")`; In fact as media said you should better use the google with 'C# datetime string format' for example